# explode() each element in array, yielding multidimensional array

Tags: php, explode

How can I use the PHP function `explode()` on each array entry?

For example:

```php
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $zips = $person->getZipResponsibility();
    $zips = nl2br($zips);

    $rangesArray = explode('<br />', $zips);
}
```

Returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10000-20000
    [1] => 30000-40000
)
```

This works great but now I have to explode each array part for an output like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array (
     [0] => 10000
     [1] => 20000
  )
  [1] => Array (
     [0] => 30000
     [1] => 40000
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work, haven't tested.

```
$rArray = array();

foreach($rangesArray as $key=>$val) {
    $rArray[] = explode('-', $val);
}
```

Comment: With respect, I think my answer is closer since it outputs a multi-dim array which is what you requested in your original question.

Comment: @user1477388 This iteration will also create a multi-dim array since it is assigning an array to each `$rArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use another explode, this time like this: `explode('-', $i);`.  You'll have to put it in a foreach like this:

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($rangesArray as $i)
{
  $arr = explode('-', $i);
  foreach ($arr as $j)
  {
    $arr1[$x] = $j;
  }
  $x++;
}

var_dump($arr1);
```

Comment: Accidentally deleted it, but ya, $x is not necessary.