# Split array values into multi dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => SecRuleEngine On 
    [1] => SecRequestBodyAccess On
)
```

How to turn the array above into this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 
        Array ( 
            [0] => SecRuleEngine 
            [1] => On
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => SecRequestBodyAccess 
            [1] => On
        )
   )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explode() each element in array, yielding multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322801/explode-each-element-in-array-yielding-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Near dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29401817/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/3015878/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It processes each entry in the input array in turn and uses explode to turn each value into an array of two values, the first being the part of the input value to the left of the space, and the second being the part to the right i.e. `'SecRuleEngine On'` is transformed to `['SecRuleEngine', 'On']`.

```
$input = array('SecRuleEngine On', 'SecRequestBodyAccess On');
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $in) {
    $output[] = explode(' ', $in);
}
print_r($output);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SecRuleEngine
            [1] => On
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SecRequestBodyAccess
            [1] => On
        )

)
```

Comment: Not me but I can see why, it crossed my mind to do so also. You have no explanation or comment to your code. That is not a proper answer

Comment: @Andreas fair comment. It was a bit rushed. I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to achieve such a result, as shown below:

```
<?php
    # The initial array with its string elements.
    $array = ["SecRuleEngine On", "SecRequestBodyAccess On"];

    # Explode each element at the space producing array with 2 values.
    $new_array = array_map(function ($current) {
        return explode(" ", $current);
    }, $array);

    # Print the new array.
    var_dump($new_array);
?>
```

[Here](https://3v4l.org/pBqdG) is a live example illustrating the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the exact result as you want. Just try this:

```
$input = ['SecRuleEngine On', 'SecRequestBodyAccess On'];
$output = [];
foreach($input as $item){
    array_push($output,explode(' ',$item));
}

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to iterate over each item, then use it to create a new array:

```
$input = ['SecRuleEngine On', 'SecRequestBodyAccess On'];
$output = [];
foreach($input as $item)
{
    $keyval = explode(' ', $item);
    $output[] = [$keyval[0]=>$keyval[1]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_map()`.

```
$array = ['SecRuleEngine On', 'SecRequestBodyAccess On'];

$new_array = array_map(function($item){ return explode(' ', $item); },  $array);

print_r($new_array);
```